# How to wait for BackgroundWorker to finish without killing ProgressBar?

Tags: vb.net, progress-bar, backgroundworker

The application is doing a lot more than this, but I have narrowed down the issue with the example below.

When bgwDone.WaitOne() is commented out, the progress bar works fine, cancel button is effective, but execution continues before the background process is complete.

When bgwDone.WaitOne() is applied, the ProgressForm is visible but not enabled, so processing cannot be cancelled and progress bar does not refresh, and the most confusing part, Msgbox("1") *does not execute*. I only see Msgbox("2") after the background worker finishes. I am utterly perplexed.

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Form1
    Private WithEvents bgw As BackgroundWorker
    Private Event bgwCancelled()
    Private bgwDone As New System.Threading.AutoResetEvent(False)

    'Allows ProgressForm to cancel execution
    Public Sub bgwCancelAsync()
        RaiseEvent bgwCancelled()
    End Sub

    Private Sub bgw_Cancelled_by_ProgressForm() Handles Me.bgwCancelled
        bgw.CancelAsync()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
        bgw = New BackgroundWorker
        bgw.WorkerReportsProgress = True
        bgw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
        If bgw.IsBusy = False Then
            ProgressForm.Show()
            bgw.RunWorkerAsync(10)
        End If

        '********THIS LINE: bgwDone.WaitOne() MAKES A BIG DIFFERENCE*******
        bgwDone.WaitOne()
        MsgBox("1")
        MsgBox("2")
        Cursor = Cursors.Default
    End Sub

    'BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync raises the DoWork event
    Private Sub bgw_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bgw.DoWork
        Dim numToDo As Integer = CInt(e.Argument)
        For n As Integer = 1 To numToDo
            If bgw.CancellationPending Then
                Exit For
            End If
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)
            bgw.ReportProgress(n * 10)
        Next
        bgwDone.Set()
    End Sub

    'ReportProgress raises the ProgressChanged event
    Private Sub bgw_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles bgw.ProgressChanged
        ProgressForm.UpdateProgress(e.ProgressPercentage)
    End Sub

    Private Sub bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object,
             e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles bgw.RunWorkerCompleted
        ProgressForm.Close()
    End Sub
```

And my form with the ProgressBar:

```
Public Class ProgressForm
    Private Sub ButtonCancel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonCancel.Click
        Form1.bgwCancelAsync()
    End Sub  

    Public Sub UpdateProgress(pct As Integer)
        ProgressBar1.Value = pct
        ProgressBar1.Refresh()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: It might help to know what you are trying to do.  You are invoking `WaitOne` on the UI thread which seems odd.  If you want to emulate a long running task in `DoWork` put the Sleep and Report inside the loop or they only happen once.      Also it appears you are using default form instances (ie the class names, `Form1` and `ProgressForm`) which is often trouble with Threads.

Comment: @Plutonix Sleep and Report are in the loop. Reporting works fine without the `WaitOne`. My actual application is parsing CNC G code, making changes. There is actually no GUI for production use, only for initial setup and testing. Filename is fed to it as a command line arg. It works fine as-is, but I thought it would be neat to add a progress bar since it takes a several seconds for larger files. How would the name `ProgressForm` cause trouble?

Comment: Yes they are inside the loops.  Sorry, I think I was tired and/or hungry at the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish.  But it almost seems like some of your code is trying to defeat the purpose of a `BackGroundWorker`:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
    bgw = New BackgroundWorker
    ...
    If bgw.IsBusy = False Then
        ProgressForm.Show()
        bgw.RunWorkerAsync(10)
    End If

    bgwDone.WaitOne()
    MsgBox("1")
    MsgBox("2")
    Cursor = Cursors.Default
End Sub
```

The purpose of a `BackgroundWorker` is to do some long running task on another thread and leave the UI responsive.  I am not sure that a task that only "*takes several seconds*" qualifies as a long running task.

- Given that, *why* use the `WaitCursor` while the BGW runs? The point to leaving the UI resposive is to allow the user to do other things in the meantime.
- The test for `bgw.IsBusy` can never, ever be true - you just created it 3 lines earlier.  Click the button again and you will create another BGW.
- The rest of the code in the click *looks like* you want or expect the code to continue on the next line after the `BGW` completes. That's not how it works.

  - If the app cannot continue without those tasks being completed, disable anything that lets the user go elsewhere until the worker completes or:
  - Forego the worker and put the form in wait mode (`Me.UseWaitCursor`) until the stuff is loaded.  This doesn't rule out a `ProgressBar`.
- A dedicated Progress Form can make sense in cases where the app will use various workers at various times.  A `StatusBar` can contain a `ProgressBar` and is much more subtle (and perhaps appropriate since it *is* a status element).

So, revised and using a form instance for the progress reporter:

#### MainForm

```
Private WithEvents bgw As BackgroundWorker
Private frmProg As ProgressForm

Public Sub New()
    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()
    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    bgw = New BackgroundWorker
End Sub

Private Sub btnLoadAll_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLoadAll.Click

    bgw.WorkerReportsProgress = True
    bgw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True

    If bgw.IsBusy = False Then
        ' create ProgressForm instance if needed
        If frmProg Is Nothing Then frmProg = New ProgressForm
        frmProg.Show()
        bgw.RunWorkerAsync(78)
    End If
    btnLoadAll.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub bgw_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bgw.DoWork
    ' multiple workers can use the same event
    Dim thisWorker = DirectCast(sender, BackgroundWorker)
    Dim count = Convert.ToInt32(e.Argument)

    For n As Integer = 1 To count
        If thisWorker.CancellationPending Then
            Exit For
        End If
        ' Fake work:
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50)
        ' dont assume the size of the job if
        ' there are multiple BGW or tasks
        thisWorker.ReportProgress(Convert.ToInt32((n / count) * 100))
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub bgw_ProgressChanged(sender As Object,
                        e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles bgw.ProgressChanged
    frmProg.UpdateProgress(e.ProgressPercentage)
End Sub

Private Sub bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object,
                        e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles bgw.RunWorkerCompleted
    If e.Error IsNot Nothing Then
        '... ToDo
    ElseIf e.Cancelled Then
        '... ToDo
    Else
        frmProg.Close()
        ' avoid 'cannot access disposed object':
        frmProg = Nothing

        Me.btnNextStep.Enabled = True
        btnLoadAll.Enabled = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Rather than enabling a "Next" button, the app could automatically proceed.  It depends on the app.

Comment: Thank you. I do have BackgroundWorker backwards, trying to implement it as an afterthought. There will be no "Next" button, so I would want the app to proceed automatically, but only after the worker has finished. That is why I tried WaitOne(), which still has the problematic effect it had before. The Msgbox() calls in the question represent subs that follow afterwards in my app. Maybe a BackgroundWorker is not the best way for the ProgressBar to be refreshed in this case.

Comment: You dont have to "wait for a bgw to finish" (the title), it will *tell* you when it is done.  Just dont do anything until that happens.  But as I said, something that only takes a few seconds doesnt really call for a ProgressBar, IMO